# Xamarin Forms, error in the Master Details

Tags: xamarin.forms, master-detail

When I return to the Root Page with this method:

```
Page page = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TrasfMagaPage), session);
                    Navigation.InsertPageBefore(page, Navigation.NavigationStack[0]);
                    await Navigation.PopToRootAsync(true);
```

The icon of the hamburger menu disappears from the TopBar.

I use the same code with all the other pages, but only in this case it presents the problem.

How is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written code similar to this to prevent a **white flicker** that appears in Android master detail pages. When inserting a page before the root, I use the `Navigation` of the **Detail** page.

```cs
Detail.Navigation.InsertPageBefore(page, root);
await Detail.Navigation.PopToRootAsync(false);
```